# overriding JQuery .click() function

Tags: jquery, click, overriding

i'm having a bit of a prblem with the jquery click function, below is part of the layout of my code:

```
<td id="01" class="day-main-diary">
    <div title="sdfsdf" class="diary-event ui-corner-all">
        <span id="delete"></span>
        <div class="diary-event-title ui-corner-all">
            sdfsdf
        </div>
        <div class="diary-event-body ui-corner-all">
            <p class="hyphenate">sdfsdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

The title, text in diary-event-title and text in diary-event-body are all dynamically generated and the class 'day-main-diary' has a click function bound to it (the actual code in the js file is:

```
$('.day-main-diary').click(function(){
   // Code is here
}
```

i am looking for a way for a click event to be recognised on the span with the id of 'delete',
amongst other things i have tried

```
$('.day-main-diary #delete').click(function(){
```

and

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
```

however, each time it completely ignores this event and always calls the day-main diary click event.

can anyone help me? i will be eternally greatfull
-Matt

Comment: does your `span#delete` have any dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remember that there can only be one `#delete` ID on the page. If there's more than one, you'll have issues, and should make it a class `.delete`.

If the `#delete` element isn't present when the page loads (dynamic) you can use `.live()`, which will take care of handling the event for you, no matter when you add the element.

```
$('#delete').live('click', function(){
           ...
 });
```

But note that this will *still* fire the event on the `.day-main-diary` as well.

One other option would be to call `.delegate()` on the `.day-main-diary` (as long as it is there when the page loads). This is similar to `.live()` but is more localized.

```
$('.day-main-diary').delegate('#delete', 'click', function() {
        ...
});
```

This also will fire the `click` on the `.day-main-diary`. Not sure what the expected behavior is.

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Yet another option would be to test the `e.target` of the click in the `.day-main-diary` click handler. If it is the `#delete` do one thing, if not, do another.

```
$('.day-main-diary').click(function( e ) {
    if(e.target.id === 'delete') {
       // run code for the delete button
    } else {
       // do something else 
    }
});
```

Otherwise, still assuming that the `#delete` is dynamic, you can bind the `.click()` *when* you create it.

```
$('<span id="delete">delete</span>').click(function( e ) {
       // your code
       // uncomment the line below if you don't want the 
       //    click event to fire on .day-main-diary as well
       // e.stopPropagation()
})
.appendTo('day-main-diary');
```

Comment: The edit you made was spot on, using the e.target worked beautifully, thanks :)